# Saving Scripts for PythonTurtle

Tags: python, import, turtle-graphics

I downloaded PythonTurtle to begin teaching my son how to program. I would like to be able to create functions for it and save them in a separate file (and his as well to save his work). However, the file does not contain the proper scope to access the commands to make the turtle draw. Is there a way I can run my file as if I had just typed it into the GUI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lol. I figured it out 10 seconds after posting this but posted it after searching for 20 minutes!

```
execfile("myfuncs.py")
```